# NameError: name 'SCOPES' is not defined authentication google calendar

Tags: python, authentication, scopes

im new in python. Now im working in my first project to create program with google calendar API.
If i run the program it should be checks the token to connect with my google account. If not, it will be open browser to login with a google account. Yesterday everything is fine, when there is no token, it will be open browser login, if it already exists, it will continue reading the event calendar

today when i wanted to run the program, this error happened.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 281, in _process_message
    return_val = _exposed_functions[message['name']](*message['args'])
  File "main.py", line 41, in Asking
    SERVICE = authenticate_google()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\TA\gui\auth_handler.py", line 21, in authenticate_google
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("credentials.json", SCOPES)
NameError: name 'SCOPES' is not defined
```

i really dont know what i did, this is my code in auth_handler.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import eel #gui

eel.init('web')

def authenticate_google():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
        with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("credentials.json", SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=creds)
    return service

@eel.expose
def delete_token():
    if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
        os.remove("token.pickle")
        print("Successfully signed out")
        eel.validate_acc("Successfully signed out")
    else:
        print("You already signed out")
        eel.validate_acc("Already signed out")
```

Help me please

Comment: Although from your question, I'm not sure about the scopes you want to use, it seems that your script shown in your question doesn't declare `SCOPES`. I think that the error message is due to this. Where is `SCOPES` in your actual script? If it is not declared, how about putting `SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']` and `SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']` to your script and reauthorize again? At that time, I would like to recommend to rename or remove the existing `token.pickle`.

Comment: @Tanaike yesss correct thankyou, i also knew the problem this morning. 
btw i already put SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']  on another file that import the auth_handler. (so the main function is there and the function is calling the auth_handler.py). The fact is I have tried on another compuer with the same project and it works.

i dont know why its not working on my fisrt computer

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although unfortunately, I'm not sure about your actual environment of `my fisrt computer`, in that case, when `SCOPE` is directly declared to the script shown in your question, what result will you obtain?

Comment: There's a really massive list of Google API scopes here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

As @Tanalike points out, if you change the scopes, you'll need to remove the token file.